Почему выводит None?
p = ["Telescopes", "Glasses", "Eyes", "Monocles"]

def sort_by_length(arr):
    return arr.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

print(sort_by_length(p))


list.sort()

Не возвращает значения, изменяет текущий список. Нужно или
return sorted(arr,key=len, reverse=True)

или
arr.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
return arr

